# VirtualCenter Server service terminated with service-specific error 2 (0x2)

Tags: vmware-vcenter

This is not a critical case but really annoying.
I'm running vCenter 4 (Build 208156) and when we reeboot the server the VirtualCenter Server service can't start and gives the following error "The VMware VirtualCenter Server service terminated with service-specific error 2 (0x2)." And if I try to start the service it fails again giving the same error. What I'll need to do is to stop the IIS Admin service and then start the VirtualCenter Server service and then the IIS Admin service, and everything runs fine until the next reboot.
Can someone tell me how to fix this annoying error?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I have the same pb. And the pb is the the IIS procces takes the port 80 before the VirtualCenter Server service. That is why the VirtualCenter Server service can not start. You have to disable IIS Admin service or change the port in IIS.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to open services and change the IIS Admin Service to delayed start